# Optimizing minimum distance calculations between multiple polygons in R

Tags: r, distance, performance, code-review, multi-polygon

I have a list of polygons and would like to create a minimum distance matrix by calculating the minimum distance between each possible pair. I am currently using the code below, but this is running really slow.

Is there a way to optimize this?

```
list #dataframe with all my multipolygons
distance<-as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=nrow(list),nrow=nrow(list)))#create an empty dataframe which I can then fill with distances.

for (i in 1:nrow(list)){
  for (j in i+1:nrow(list)){ 

      distance[j,i] <- st_distance(x = list[i,], y= list[j,], by_element = TRUE)

  }
}
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/67277986/820534

Comment: What spatial library are you using?

Comment: If you did `st_distance(list)` you'd get a full distance matrix. Why don't you use that?

Comment: I have 2 considerations for improving speed:

**(1)** If this does not comprise your result, try to simplify the geometry of your shapefiles (i.e. reduce the number of vertices in the polygones). Usualy a distance function calculates the distances between all vertices and then picks the min. This could reduce computational cost. 

**(2)** Try different functions: 
**(2a)** try the `sf_distance()` function from the `sf` package instead. It's very efficient from what I know, likewise you could try the
**(2b)** `gDistance()` from `rgeos`